# Differentiation of norm in Banach space (explanation of text needed)

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, banach-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $Y$ be uniformly smooth Banach space. Consider the convex $C^1$ functional $\Phi:Y \to \mathbb{R}$ defined
$$\Phi(y) = \frac{1}{q}\Vert y \Vert^q_{Y}.$$

> Its derivative $\varphi:Y \to Y'$ is a monotone operator satisfying
>   $$\langle \varphi(y), y \rangle = \Vert y \Vert^q_Y.$$

How to prove this? I presume this refers to the Gateaux derivative but I cannot get anywhere after forming the directional derivative expression. Is the proof hard?

> Let $u \in L^p_{loc}(0,T;X) \cap L^q_{loc}(0,T;Y)$ be such that $\varphi(u) \in L^{q'}_{loc}(0,T;Y')$ is weakly differentiable with $(\varphi(u))' \in L^{p'}_{loc}(0,T;X')$. Then
>   $$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{q'}\Vert u(t) \Vert^q_Y = \langle (\varphi(u))', u \rangle$$
>   holds in the sense of distributions on $(0,T)$.

I don't obtain this: I don't get the factor of $\frac{1}{q'}$. I get:
$$-\int_0^T \psi(t)\langle (\varphi(u))', u \rangle = \int_0^T \psi'(t)\langle (\varphi(u)), u \rangle = \int_0^T \psi'(t)\Vert u(t) \Vert^q$$
by the equation above. So I get
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Vert u(t) \Vert^q_Y = \langle (\varphi(u))', u \rangle.$$
Where did I go wrong? Thanks for any help.

**EDIT** Source is http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10492-012-0004-0, section A.3 in the appendix.

Comment: Assuming $\Phi$ is Frechet differentiable, then $\langle\varphi(y),y\rangle$ is the Gateaux derivative of $\Phi$ in the $y$ direction, so can be computed explicitly as $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h} \left( \Phi(y + hy) - \Phi(y)\right)$. Note that $\Phi(y+hy) = (1+h)^q \Phi(y)$ by the scaling homogeneity of the norm. The derivative is not that hard to compute.

Comment: For your second quote, in what sense is the pairing $\langle,\rangle$? If it is the $X, X'$ pairing, then when you were integrating by parts, why does the time derivative not fall on $u$ itself? I think the correct computation is probably something like
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \| u(t)\|^q_Y = \langle \varphi(u(t)),u'(t)\rangle = \frac{d}{dt} \langle \varphi(u(t)),u(t)\rangle - \langle \varphi(u(t))',u\rangle $$
and then you use the first part and regroup terms.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks, I think it is the $X,X'$ pairing. Sorry can you explain the first equality in your last comment?

Comment: that's the chain rule for derivatives.